# React Native + Redux: How to properly pass in props to action callers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have the following set up, with all the methods with .bind(this) in the constructor. So the user enters in username and password in the inputs and get updated in state, and the component gets re-rerendered and newly updated state `this.props.username` and `this.props.password` get passed down. I would then want to pass them into an action creator called `this.props.registerUser()` once Register button is clicked.

So I was wondering, what's the right practice to pass in the newly updated props to an action creator?

**For example**

Is it `_handleRegister(this.props.username, this.props.password)` then `this.props.registerUser(this.props.username, this.props.password)`? Or simply `this.props.registerUser(this.props.username, this.props.password)`? Or a combination of `this._handleRegister(this.props.username, this.props.password)` and former?

```
  _handleRegister() {
    this.props.registerUser()
  }

  render() {

    return (
     <View> 
      <TextInput
        placeholder={'Username'}
        onChangeText={...}
        value={this.props.username}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder={'Password'}
        onChangeText={...}
        value={this.props.password}
      />
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._handleRegister}>
        <Text>Register</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>           
     </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass prameters to `_handleRegister`

```
_handleRegister() {
    const { username, password, registerUser } = this.props;
    registerUser(username, password);
}
```

Additional tip: you can skip return keyword by doing:

```
render() (
  <View>
     ...
  </View>
)
```

Comment: Sorry but is `const =` a typo? Is it supposed to just be `const`?

Comment: sorry my bad @LyManeug

Comment: @SaidKholov Works beautifully! Thank you so much. Accepted answer and upvoted. One more question if you don't mind, when would be the case to use return() especially?

Comment: Don't use it as you'll always have to wrap your return in one element

Comment: @SaidKholov sorry but could you clarify on one element? Also, I need to pass the properties in as an object. Should form the object inside the `_updateRegister` before passing into the action creator or pass the props in individually and handle forming the object inside the action caller itself?

Comment: It depends on your implementation and semantics of your function

Comment: @SaidKholov but just in general case. Typically in the action caller?

Comment: Yes, I find myself doing it more often